# How to change the date format from MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have a date column in a table stored as `MM/DD/YYYY` format. I have to select and store the same date in another table in `YYYY-MM-DD` format i.e. XSD Date Format. But I am not able to do it. I am using this query:

```
select to_date(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD') from table;
```

But still I am not able to do it.  Giving me error

> ORA-01843 : not a valid month

Comment: Applying `to_date()` on a date column makes no sense. Also date columns are not stored "with a format". The format is applied by the client application (e.g. SQL*Plus) when displaying the date.

Comment: Okay.. i will clear it to you. The date as what i can see in my table is like e.g. 6/21/2006 and now I have to select this date and convert it into 2006-06-21. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Exactly which datatype does that column have?

Comment: If the column is really a `DATE` then `top_char()` is the way to go as shown by Yahia. `select to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD')` will **not** produce the error you are showing us.

Comment: *"Okay.. i will clear it to you"* Actually the Seeker never made it clear what they were trying to achieve, because they never answered the question about the **data type** of the column they were trying to format. A correct answer to the question hinges on this point. Although as they don't appear to have visited this site since 2012 I guess they don't really care any more whether they get an answer 8-/

Answer (score 84):

use

```
select to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD') from table;
```

Comment: I tried it already its not working. Throwing error as i mentioned above.

Comment: it is not the same thing as you tried. It is to_
char, not to_date.

Comment: but wont to_char change the dataype from DATE to CHAR ?? I require it to be in DATE datatype only.

Comment: a real DATE column does NOT have any format! if you want date to be in a specific format the result is no longer a DATE type - it becomes a string... XML contains (aside from special binary cases) exclusively strings... what exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I have this column which is having datatype DATE in a table. I have this date e.g. 6/21/2006 in this table. I need to select this date and have to insert it to another table in 2006-06-21 format in a column of DATE type. From this second table i am fetching the data and creating the XML to send to some other target. At the target the same date would be fetched from the XML and would be saved in there table having column with DATE type.

Comment: sorry, but what you describe is a paradox... any format (be it "YYYY-MM-DD" or "MM/DD/YYYY" or whatever) is ALWAYS a string (i.e. VARCHAR2) AND ANY XML is a string (seldomn exceptional cases aside)... DATE datatype itself has NO FORMAT AT ALL! so what you describe can only be true in parts, not completely - from your description it is impossible for me to figure out the real datatypes thus I don't know how to help :-(

Answer (score 22):

It sounds like you've got it the wrong way round. If your *existing* data is in MM/DD/YYYY format, then you want:

```
select to_date(date_column,'MM/DD/YYYY') from table;
```

to convert the existing data to DATE values. (I do wonder why they're not stored as dates, to be honest...)

If you want to perform the conversion in one step, you might want:

```
select to_char(to_date(date_column,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from table;
```

In other words, for each row, parse it in MM/DD/YYYY format, then reformat it to YYYY-MM-DD format.

(I'd still suggest trying to keep data in its "natural" type though, rather than storing it as text in the first place.)

Comment: also note that without the `to_char` part, the result that your application will output will depend on the NLS parameters.

Comment: there is absolutely not need to apply `to_date` on a date colum.

Comment: This column is DATE format only still it is showing the errors. And when i use the first query of yours then again it shows the same error. (not a valid month.) I have to select and send this date in a XML so i require the date in XSD date format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I had believed when reading the question that the values were stored as MM/DD/YYYY in a VARCHAR column. I supposed Jon Skeet also believed that

Comment: @Benoit: the it makes sense ;) I was relying on "*have a date column*" to be true

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The question is definitely unclear. Given that the OP is talking about a "date column in a table stored as MM/DD/YYYY" I'm assuming it's *actually* a varchar field.

Answer (score 10):

I assume that you can use the Oracle SQL Developer, which you can download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html).

You can define the date format which you want to work with:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd';
```

With this, now you can perform a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM emp_company WHERE JDate = '2014-02-25'
```

If you want to be more specific you can define the date format like this:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

Answer (score 5):

To convert a `DATE` column to another format, just use `TO_CHAR()` with the desired format, then convert it back to a `DATE` type:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_column, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') from my_table
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select to_date(to_char(ORDER_DATE,'YYYY/MM/DD')) 
from ORDERS;
```

This might help but, at the end you will get a string not the date. Apparently, 
 your format problem will get solved for sure .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply by :

```
select to_char(to_date(date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from table
```

Answer (score 2):

For military time formatting,

```
select TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss') from DUAL

--2018-07-10 15:07:15
```

If you want your date to round DOWN to Month, Day, Hour, Minute, you can try

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "full-date" --2018-07-11 10:40:26
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'year'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-year"-- 2018-01-01 00:00:00
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'month'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-month" -- 2018-07-01 00:00:00
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'day'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-Sunday" -- 2018-07-08 00:00:00
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'dd'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-day" -- 2018-07-11 00:00:00
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'hh'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-hour" -- 2018-07-11 10:00:00
, TO_CHAR( TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mi'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "trunc-to-minute" -- 2018-07-11 10:40:00
from DUAL
```

For formats literals, you can find help in 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions242.htm#SQLRF52037

Comment: still engaging strong in 2021 in VS-2019 pulling from Oracle source for validation queries.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, the data-type in the datatable is DATE.
So you should simply use:
"select date_column from table;"

Now if you execute the select you will get back a date data-type, which should be what you need for the .xsd.

Culture-dependent formating of the date should be done in the GUI (most languages have convenient ways to do so), not in the select-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Basically , Data in a Date column in Oracle can be stored in any user defined format or kept as default.
It all depends on NLS parameter.

Current format can be seen by : SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

If you try to insert a record and insert statement is NOT in THIS format then it will give :
ORA-01843 : not a valid month  error.
So first change the database date format before insert statements ( I am assuming you have bulk load of insert statements) and then execute insert script.

Format can be changed by :
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Also You can Change NLS settings from SQL Developer GUI , (Tools > preference> database > NLS)

Ref: http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-sql-l/how-to-view-current-date-format-1992815

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me! You can convert to datatype you want be it a date or string

```
to_char(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(end_date),'MM-DD-YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS end_date
```

Comment: This is the right answer if you want a Date data type as output.

Comment: This redundantly converts the date to a string, into a date, then back to a string and the result will be identical to to_char(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Answer (score 1):

Late reply but for.databse-date-type the following line works.

```
SELECT to_date(t.given_date,'DD/MM/RRRR') response_date FROM Table T
```

given_date's column type is Date

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggy back off of Yahia, if you have a timestamp you can use this function to cast exclusively as date, removing the timestamps.

```
TO_CHAR(CAST(DateTimeField AS DATE), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Or in my case I need the below format

```
TO_CHAR(CAST(DateTimeField AS DATE), 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for some reason the function CONVERT doesnt work for me, then i had to:

```
SELECT
to_char(to_date(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(date1),'DD/MM/YYYY')), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM DUAL;
```

It works for timestamps like this:
06/10/22 08:56:32,576906

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(date_column,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM table;
```

Answer (score -2):

if you need to change your column output date format just use to_char this well get you a string, not a date.

Answer (score -3):

use

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_column,'%Y-%m-%d') from table;
```

also gothrough

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Ohh..It is really big mistake. I don't know how I missed that. sorry guys.