# Datetime to Varchar2 conversion

Tags: datetime, plsql

The date value from one of my table is coming as 2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z and I need to display the same value as 15/2/2016 6:30:00 PM.

I am trying to use TO_CHAR as below:

```
a:=2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z
b:= TO_CHAR(a, 'MM/D/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
```

but it isn't working at all.

Comment: This is invalid PL/SQL: `a:=2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606745/how-to-change-the-date-format-from-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-pl-sql U find here what you are looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to a is not valid in PL/SQL.  Try this:

```
declare
   a date;
   b varchar2(20);
begin
   a:= timestamp '2016-02-15 18:30:00.000';
   b:= TO_CHAR(a, 'MM/D/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
   dbms_output.put_Line(b);
end;
```

I have improved on the code in your comment below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_project_launch_date
   ( p_form_id_param IN NUMBER )
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   project_launch_date VARCHAR2(100);
   temp TIMESTAMP;
   temp1 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   --fetching the doc created by information ;
   SELECT ANSWER INTO project_launch_date
     FROM table 
    WHERE QUESTION_ID = id 
      AND FORM_ID = p_form_id_param;
   temp := to_timestamp(project_launch_date,
                       'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"');
   temp1 := TO_CHAR(temp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUTPUT =' || temp1);
   RETURN temp;
END;
```

Comment: Function i am using:  
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_project_launch_date
(
    p_form_id_param IN NUMBER
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    project_launch_date VARCHAR2(100);
    temp VARCHAR2(100);
    temp1 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    --fetching the doc created by information ;
     SELECT 
        ANSWER INTO project_launch_date 
        FROM table
        WHERE QUESTION_ID = id AND FORM_ID = p_form_id_param;
        temp := timestamp '(project_launch_date)';
        temp1 := TO_DATE(temp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUTPUT =' || temp1);
    RETURN temp;
END;
/

Comment: [Error] PLS-00166 (17: 17): PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal

Comment: My output of the first query is in the format: **2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z**

Comment: Then you need to modify it, because Oracle does not accept 'T' and 'Z' in date or timestamp values.  Perhaps using `translate(project_launch_date,'xTZ','x')`.  And consider using the DATE or TIMESTAMP data types instead of just VARCHAR2 for everything.

Comment: This makes no sense: `temp := timestamp '(project_launch_date)';`

Comment: @TonyAndrews, you don't need the translate in your attempt to convert the string into a timestamp. You could just do: `to_timestamp(str, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"Z"')`

Comment: Ah yes - now you say that I've made that mistake before!

Comment: I tried but i am still getting the conversion error messages

Comment: I am using below code:              SELECT ANSWER INTO project_launch_date
            FROM INTAKE_FORM_ANSWERS_DATA WHERE QUESTION_ID = 25  AND FORM_ID = p_form_id_param;
            temp := TO_TIMESTAMP(project_launch_date,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"');
            temp1 := TO_CHAR(temp,'DD/MM/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUTPUT =' || temp1);

Answer (score 0):

> Based on your requirement this date format is not recognized by
>   Oracle. You need to tweak the input so that oracle recognize it. Hope
>   below snippet helps you.

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  lv_input VARCHAR2(100):='2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z';
  lv_date  TIMESTAMP;
  lv_out_req VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(REPLACE(lv_input,'T',' '),'Z',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
  INTO lv_date
  FROM DUAL;
  dbms_output.put_line('Input varchar '||lv_input||' --> '||lv_date);
  lv_out_req:=to_char(lv_date,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
  dbms_output.put_line('Out formated varchar '||lv_out_req);
END;

---------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Input varchar 2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z --> 02/15/2016 18:30:00.000000
Out formated varchar 02/15/2016 18:30:00

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: When i ran your code, i got **Input varchar 2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z --> 15-FEB-16 06.30.00.000000 PM** as out put. And when i making the date format change to meet my requirements, i am getting **Not a valid month** error message. Code: SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(REPLACE(project_launch_date,'T',' '),'Z',''),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF6')
  INTO lv_date FROM DUAL;

Comment: Please check the the input and per that use format mask. This is the issue with format mask you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this in Oracle:

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('2016-02-15T18:30:00.000Z','YYYY-MM DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.ff3"Z"'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS AM') from dual
```